# How to make Hugo render blockquotes?

Tags: hugo

I have the following post (`content/posts/YYYY-MM-DD-title.md` file) in my Hugo project:

```
---
title: My title 
author: Franz Drollig
date: 2019-08-17T16:33:13+00:00
url: /funny-quote/
categories:
  - Quote

---
<blockquote class="wp-block-quote">
  <p>
    First paragraph of the quote 
  </p>

  <p>
    Second paragraph of the quote. 
  </p>

  <p>
    Punch line. 
  </p>
</blockquote>

Author of the quote
```

Right now, only the last part (`Author of the quote`) is rendered. The actual quote does not appear.

[image: Screenshot]

What do I need to do in order for the text inside `<blockquote>` to be rendered properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started to render that content after I added

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
unsafe= true
```

to `config.toml` as suggested [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/raw-html-getting-omitted-in-0-60-0/22032).